# How can i count currently connected users in my lotus application (nsf)?

Tags: session, xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

I have an xpage application and i simply want to count open sessions (anonymous users) or logged in users or both, and display this info on a page.
This question http://bit.ly/1sUMt8m is still open without solution.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Is it a public site, or intranet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain this information from the console.  **show users** will give you all users and their open databases. **show opendatabases** shows the databases and reads. See the [documentation](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_admin.nsf/89d3962efd85426f85256b870069c0aa/532d24fff82ae29685256c1d0039e3dc?OpenDocument) for details.

So you could use sessionAsSigner and issue the console command from your code. Add -xml to get the response in a format you can parse with certainty. 
The measure is slightly crude since a user could have closed a window while the session is still valid.

Short of that you would need some JS trickery

Comment: wouldn't it show me the sessions on the server instead of a specific nsf application? is there any info in the xml about which app the session was opened in? (so as to filter the xml and show them)

Comment: Updated the answer. The show commands would give you the information you seek.